# Nginx catch all and catch all redirect causes binary download

Tags: nginx, https, 301-redirect

I have server which must serve only HTTPS, and I can have domains or subdomains created dynamically by users and be handled by application itself.

I tried to use return and redirect but when accessing the site via **http**, it asks to download a binary file.

Here is my config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  # any of option below gives same behaviour
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent; 
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
        listen 443 http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 http2;

        ssl    on;

        server_name _;
        port_in_redirect off;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/app.xx.com.br.access.log combined;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/app.xx.com.br.error.log;

        root /var/www/html/app.xx.com.br/public_html;
        index index.html;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.com.br/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.com.br/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

CURL Request / Response

```
MB-Pro-2:~ user$ curl -v http://app.host.com.br
* Rebuilt URL to: http://app.host.com.br/
*   Trying 18.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to app.proiot.com.br (18.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: app.host.com.br
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection #0 to host app.host.com.br left intact
���
```

If I look on Firefox inspector for response (���) I have:
[image]

It is just not redirecting.

Comment: Check headers with `curl -I http://...`. Browser could cache responces

Comment: I get curl: (8) Weird server reply

Comment: Post full request and response for `curl -v http://your-host/`

Comment: Just edited my question with more info. It is not redirecting. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have enabled http2 for port 80. Check out *all* other server blocks.

Comment: you got to the point, a copy paste mistake in another config file. Didn't know the symptom when using http2 on 80. Please feel free to post your answer and I will accept it. Thank  you very much